# Lucene updateDocument not deleting documents

Tags: java, lucene, yammer

this seems a common problem, except I have had no trouble with this before and the usual fix does not work. It is probably something silly, but I can not find it.

I want to index a yammer site as the yammer api is not fast enough for my purpose, problem is that when I try to update my index using the updateDocument functionality the old ones are not deleted. But I have a stored unique key that is not analysed.

Here is the relevant code:

```
Document newdoc = new Document();
newdoc.add(new Field(YammerMessageFields.URL, resultUrl, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
newdoc.add(new Field(YammerMessageFields.THREAD_ID, threadID.toString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
newdoc.add(new Field(YammerMessageFields.AUTHOR, senderName, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
newdoc.add(new Field(YammerMessageFields.CONTENTS, resultText, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
Term key = new Term(YammerMessageFields.THREAD_ID, newdoc.getFieldable(YammerMessageFields.THREAD_ID).toString());
logger.debug("updating document with key: " + key);
try {
    IndexWriter writer = getIndexWriter();
    writer.updateDocument(key, newdoc);
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

What I see in my log is:

```
2012-05-11 12:02:29,816 DEBUG [http-8088-2] LuceneIndex - https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/?newer_than=0
2012-05-11 12:02:38,594 DEBUG [http-8088-2] LuceneIndex - updating document with key: threadid:stored,indexed<threadid:173285202>
2012-05-11 12:02:45,167 DEBUG [http-8088-2] LuceneIndex - updating document with key: threadid:stored,indexed<threadid:173033239>
2012-05-11 12:02:51,686 DEBUG [http-8088-2] LuceneIndex - updating document with key: threadid:stored,indexed<threadid:173014568>
2012-05-11 12:02:51,871 DEBUG [http-8088-2] LuceneIndex - new items:3

2012-05-11 12:03:27,393 DEBUG [http-8088-2] YammerResource - return all documents
2012-05-11 12:03:27,405 DEBUG [http-8088-2] YammerResource - nr docs:3
2012-05-11 12:03:27,405 DEBUG [http-8088-2] YammerResource - nr dels:0

...
next update
...

2012-05-11 12:03:35,802 DEBUG [http-8088-2] LuceneIndex - https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/?newer_than=0
2012-05-11 12:03:43,933 DEBUG [http-8088-2] LuceneIndex - updating document with key: threadid:stored,indexed<threadid:173322760>
2012-05-11 12:03:50,467 DEBUG [http-8088-2] LuceneIndex - updating document with key: threadid:stored,indexed<threadid:173285202>
2012-05-11 12:03:56,982 DEBUG [http-8088-2] LuceneIndex - updating document with key: threadid:stored,indexed<threadid:173056406>
2012-05-11 12:04:03,533 DEBUG [http-8088-2] LuceneIndex - updating document with key: threadid:stored,indexed<threadid:173033239>
2012-05-11 12:04:10,097 DEBUG [http-8088-2] LuceneIndex - updating document with key: threadid:stored,indexed<threadid:173030769>
2012-05-11 12:04:16,629 DEBUG [http-8088-2] LuceneIndex - updating document with key: threadid:stored,indexed<threadid:173014568>
2012-05-11 12:04:23,169 DEBUG [http-8088-2] LuceneIndex - updating document with key: threadid:stored,indexed<threadid:173003570>
2012-05-11 12:04:23,341 DEBUG [http-8088-2] LuceneIndex - new items:7

2012-05-11 12:05:09,694 DEBUG [http-8088-1] YammerResource - return all documents
2012-05-11 12:05:09,696 DEBUG [http-8088-1] YammerResource - nr docs:10
2012-05-11 12:05:09,696 DEBUG [http-8088-1] YammerResource - nr dels:0
```

So the keys reoccur (and 4 new ones), but when this is done there are 10 documents in my store instead of 7 (and 3 deleted ones).

edit: here is how I find the items, but I actually display them and inspected it with Luke.

```
IndexReader r = IndexReader.open(searchIndex.getIndex());
                List<Document> docList = new ArrayList<Document>();
                List<Document> delList = new ArrayList<Document>();

                int num = r.numDocs();
                num += r.numDeletedDocs();
                for ( int i = 0; i < num && i < max; i++)
                {
                    if ( ! r.isDeleted( i))
                        docList.add(r.document(i));
                    else
                        delList.add(r.document(i));

                }
                r.close();
                logger.debug("nr docs:" + docList.size());
                logger.debug("nr dels:" + delList.size());
```

Comment: And what API call is used to find the doc count?

Comment: Could be. If calling `maxDoc`, it is known not to account for deleted docs. I'm talking about Lucene API call, of course. Not anything above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure without running some test code, but this looks wrong to me:

```
Term key = new Term(YammerMessageFields.THREAD_ID, 
   newdoc.getFieldable(YammerMessageFields.THREAD_ID).toString());
```

Are you sure it shouldn't be:

```
Term key = new Term(YammerMessageFields.THREAD_ID, 
   newdoc.getFieldable(YammerMessageFields.THREAD_ID).stringValue());
```

You then go on to use that key to attempt to update any matching existing document. If the key is wrong, then presumably the document update will silently fail. I suspect that the `toString()` on that `Term` will actually just give you an Object reference, which means that the update will never work.

Calling `toString()` for anything other than logging or debugging (i.e. anything with logic in it) is usually a mistake.

Comment: the .stringValue() solved the problem. Thank you, strange that this worked in another version...

Comment: No, that isn't that strange. Programmers frequently change the implementation of `toString()` methods; which is why you should never depend on them returning a specific value.

Comment: btw the update did not fail, the documents are actually added, it is just the delete that is failing.

Comment: The update is actually an atomic delete/add - I don't think there is a way to "update" documents in Lucene. See http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_4_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#updateDocument(org.apache.lucene.index.Term, org.apache.lucene.document.Document). There is nothing in there that says the add portion is aborted if the delete fails to match any docs. So - because there are no matching documents to replace the "update" fails.

Comment: @Jon There's also `StringBuilder.toString`, `StringWriter.toString` --  and quite a number of others where `toString` is **the** API.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik - True, but they are the exception, not the rule, and many classes expose a method that does the same thing as the `toString()`. IMO exposing `toString()` as part of an API is confusing and gets developers into bad habits. If there is an alternative, I use it.

Comment: @Jon That is all correct, but talking from an API user's perspective, it is not crazy to think calling `toString` is a good idea. Sometimes it is, sometimes it isn't -- no blanket advice can be given except "watch your step" :) BTW what did you mean by "... will give you an Object reference"? I didn't get that part.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You get a printed String along the lines of "java.lang.Object@2687816d" which will be the default unless you overrride `toString()`.

Comment: That would be so unlike Lucene... it probably gives you a nice logger-friendly string (I think I remember using it some time ago...)

Comment: It does give you a nice logger friendly string (I'm printing it above).